# Apache reverse proxy for Mattermost: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /api/v4/websocket

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, websocket, plesk

I really need your help! I've posted this question a month ago in a lot of linux and web forums and also directly at Mattermost but without any success and I really really need this tool. So I hope you came across this problem by yourself and maybe you can help me.

Since I'm already using GitLab and GitLab comes with a build-in Mattermost installation, I used that one. After installing it, I can reach Mattermost via `127.0.0.1:8065`. So far so good but since I want to use it via an URL, I've created a subdomain in [Plesk](https://www.plesk.com/) and added some [additional Apache directives](https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213926385-How-to-add-domain-specific-Apache-or-nginx-directives-to-web-server-configuration-file-on-Plesk-for-Linux) like described [here](https://docs.mattermost.com/install/config-apache2.html?highlight=apache#configuring-apache2-as-a-proxy-for-mattermost-server-unofficial):

**HTTP:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/.well-known/.*
RewriteRule  ^/(.*)  https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1  [last,redirect=301]
```

**HTTPS:**

```
ServerName mattermost.xxx.de
ProxyPreserveHost On

RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-SSL" expr=%{HTTPS}

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} ^WebSocket$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} ^Upgrade$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://127.0.0.1:8065%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

<Location />
    Require all granted
    ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverse http://127.0.0.1:8065/
    ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 mattermost.xxx.de
</Location>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mattermost_error.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mattermos_forwarded.log common_forwarded
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mattermos_access.log combined env=!dontlog
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mattermos.log combined
```

Also I've enabled SSL for that domain directly inside Plesk with Lets Encrypt. To be sure everything works, I've also allowed unsecure connections from Mattermost because of a self-signed certificate.

I'm now able to reach Mattermost via `https` and also the certificate looks great. But now I've a big problem: The websocket don't works and I'm getting this error inside my console:

[image]

Without a websocket, a chatting tool makes no sense. Also I've found this error inside the custom error log defined in the additional directives above:

```
AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /api/v4/websocket (scheme 'ws'). If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.
```

I've researched a lot about this issue and enabled a lot of Apache modules in Plesk but without any success:

[image]

I really need this for an important dev project. I hope you know an answer - I am at the end of my rope...

Comment: That’s some relatively complicated stuff.  I’m not sure what all those rewrite rules are doing. But my gut says they aren’t needed.  I would remove them and just do they proxy rules.  If that doesn’t fix it, I’d be tempted to try nginx for the reverse proxy and see if you get different behavior that way.

Answer (score 1):

ditch the rewrite rules and use proxypassmatch

```
proxyPassMatch ^(/api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket.*)$      ws://127.0.0.1:8065/$1
```

## EDIT

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName mattermost.xxx.de

  ##ssl stuff

  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-Proto" expr=%{REQUEST_SCHEME}
  RequestHeader set "X-Forwarded-SSL" expr=%{HTTPS}

  proxyPassMatch ^(/api/v[0-9]+/(users/)?websocket.*)$ ws://127.0.0.1:8065/$1
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8065/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8065/
  ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain 127.0.0.1 mattermost.xxx.de

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/mattermost_error.log
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mattermos_forwarded.log common_forwarded
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mattermos_access.log combined env=!dontlog
  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/mattermos.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you please show me what I should replace? How much should I delete? Thanks!+

Comment: Sadly still getting the same error again: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /api/v4/websocket (scheme 'ws'). If you are using a......

Comment: did you restart your apache webserver after enabling the mod_proxy_wstunnel?

Comment: Please take a look into the question to see all enabled mods. They are still enabled. And yes, I've restarted the apache multiple times.

Comment: `sudo apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES | grep proxy` should list proxy_module, proxy_http_module, proxy_wstunnel_module.

Comment: The output: proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_ajp_module (shared)
 proxy_balancer_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_html_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 proxy_http2_module (shared)
 proxy_scgi_module (shared)
 proxy_wstunnel_module (shared)

Comment: how are you testing the websocket?

Comment: I'm opening the console and there the error gets printed. Chatting is not possible and message are not beein pushed, only when reloading the page.

Comment: Hi, any ideas? I really need to get this thing working...